# https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/120?api_key=MYAPIKey not working in Postman

Tags: video, postman

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/120?api_key=MYAPIKey

Is anyone having issue regarding the use of TMDB API? The above path is not working in Postman. Thank you for the help.

Tried it on the browser and it is working fine. But it gives 403 ERROR when I tried the same in the Postman.

Comment: For me, it returns `Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key.` in the browser.